# How does LM hash deal with passwords that are between 8 and 13 chars

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management

If its 14 then it splits it to 7&7, but how about 13 characters? 7&6?

How does it work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography and really belongs on Cryptography.SE.

Answer (score 4):

The password is padded with null bytes: extra bytes of value 0x00 are appended so that the total length is exactly 14 bytes. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash), item 4.

Of course, LM hash is a [very poor password hashing algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/is-there-any-advantage-to-splitting-a-password/2883#2883). Don't use it (if you have the choice).